Is there a way to remove duplicate dependencies using wix heat filters?
I am using wix ( v4 ) to build MSI and execute custom actions at the time of update or first install or removing program.
My application have multiple projects ( one for UI and two windows services ). I use wix heatwave along with a filter ( .xslt files ) to copy all the dependencies of a project to MSI.
I have created a post-build event that runs heatwave and create .wxs file that is being referenced in the main package.wxs files.
When project was new this approach worked fine but now there are duplicate dependencies like a file created by Project A contains
<Component Id="cmpyjDAB.WKcTwgVDE4D_sbUZAeN4U" Guid="*">
            <File Id="filQoyHtvEBAT9fl0PuEAK0iAJV518" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.projectA.TargetDir)\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
        </Component>

the same component with same ID is also created by Project B. Because of this I get the following error

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details Error   WIX0091 Duplicate symbol 'Component:cmpyjDAB.WKcTwgVDE4D_sbUZAeN4U' referenced by \projectA.Binaries.wxs(54). This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Ensure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique or use an access modifier to scope the identfier.   wix_project \projectB.Binaries.wxs.

I use the following command to for heatwave.
call "C:\Users\hp\.nuget\packages\wixtoolset.heat\4.0.3\tools\net472\x64\heat.exe" dir "$(TargetDir)."  -t "{solutionDir}\projectA.xslt" -var var.projectA.TargetDir -dr INSTALLFOLDER -cg projectA -ag -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -o "$(SolutionDir)example\$(ProjectName).Binaries.wxs" 
My filter for heatwave ( .xslt file )
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:key name="service-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')]" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="service-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.xml')]" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="service-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.dll.config')]" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="service-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.vshost.exe')]" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:key name="service-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'app.confing')]" use="@Id" />
    <!--<xsl:key name="service-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.Json.dll')]" use="@Id" />-->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('service-search', @Id)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('service-search', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>

I don't want to find duplicate dependencies  manually. Please let me know if there is another way to do all of this which in turn should solve the problem of duplicate dependencies.
